# If statement which checks if value exists and then write KML tag

Tags: c#, list, if-statement, kml

I'm working on a project which builds a KML file, taking GPS coordinates and creating placemarks for each point... 
Then another feature is about changing the picture style if something is true.

More detailed:

I have a List of strings with the values stored from a gridview. The list contains both elements with dates and empty ones as well. Then I have to check for the one which are not empty - set picture1, else set defaultPic.

Here is the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < latList.Count; i++) //looping through all the coordinates
```

{

```
kml.WriteStartElement("Placemark");
kml.WriteElementString("name", "Point " + GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text);



  if (datesList.Any(dates => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(dates) && dates != "&nbsp;") )
  {
    kml.WriteElementString("styleUrl", "#randomColorIcon");
  }
  else
  {
    kml.WriteElementString("styleUrl", "#randomColorIcon2");
  }
```

I get the KML file with all the same picture("randomColorIcon"). Since I have 3 values in the date column in the gridview (3 not empty values in the datesList respectively) I need to get 3 points with different picture, and all the others with the default one...

SO there is something wrong with the if statement but I don't really get it now. Sorry if something is not clear, I will try to fix it..

Any directions or suggestions are very welcome. Hope you can understand what do I mean with all this and help... :(

Desired KML file (There are 3 points which has dates in the database, all the other Points have the same picture)

[image: Desired KML] 
Hope it is visible...

Thanks guys

Comment: Are you missing a loop on `datesList` in your code?

Comment: Have you got some secret loop around this code that you aren't telling us about? :) Does that look at datesList too? You are nearly there.

Comment: Yes I am. And yes there is a for loop just before this... I will edit the code so u can see...

Comment: Can you please post an example of the KML you want to generate?

Comment: Yes I will do that in the Question so it's more visible...

Comment: Thanks, looks like you are getting latList and dateList from somewhere but not retaining the relationship between them. Really you could do with creating an object that contains the coordinate, and a list of dates. Then you would loop through the outer object and inside that loop loop though <b>It's</b> date list. So you get the outer loop running 20 times and the inner loop 10 for each outer object. The object will look in C# very much like your XML, you should work with that idea :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand that correct and if I need this at all.. you might be right :) Basically I use two gridviews - one with all the points (20 in this case) and another gridview which shows each different activity for each point (10 tasks) and the dates for each one of the activity (20 points x 10 activities for each = 200 rows of data) To accomplish the change of pictures I use the 2nd gridview only with the dates and tasks(activities). The first gridview is used for getting the long and lat only and displaying the name of each point ;) Can you follow it? :)

Comment: Does you second grid view have the id of the point it refers to. If it does, change your outer for loop to foreach(var lat in latList). Then you can use foreach(var dates in datesList.Where(d => d.PointId == lat.Id)) as your inner loop. This will just loop through the 10 dates that match the point in the outer loop. I made some assumptions about var names but I think you should be ok :)

Comment: Yes I think I get your point... but the two gvs are basically the same (from same datasource), just showing different information. The first one is more or less like the following command "SELECT DISTINCT ..." getting all the points. The second is the same but with 10x rows more (the 10 tasks for each point)...  I will try your suggestion soon :)

Comment: Have you thought about "nested grid view"? Do a search for it, it may help. Good luck

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6054/discussion-between-pepys-and-mark-dickinson)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
kml.WriteStartElement("Placemark");
kml.WriteElementString("name", "Point " + GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text);


foreach(var dates in datesList)
{
  if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dates)) )
  {
    kml.WriteElementString("styleUrl", "#randomColorIcon");
  }
  else
  {
    kml.WriteElementString("styleUrl", "#randomColorIcon2");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude, I tried it but I get the <styleUrl> tag 200times for each placemark (I have 200 rows in the datesList)

Comment: That is what will happen, the else takes care of that. Do the tags correspond to the contents of the list?

Comment: What do you mean if they correspond ?

Comment: Yes not the tags correspond ;) But I get the tag 200 times which is actually normal... how can I avoid this and still loop through the datesList? ... (damn I feel stupid now)

Answer (score 2):

Your if statement returns true whenever a date in the collection is not null and is not equal to blank (" ").. so if you have at least one valid date value you will be returning #randomColorIcon.

I'd use this:

```
datesList.ForEach(d =>
    kml.WriteElementString("styleUrl", (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(d) && d != "&nbsp;") ? "#randomColorIcon" : "#randomColorIcon2");
```

Comment: Subtly, it returns true if there is a date anywhere in the collection rather than if a particular item matches the criteria in the lambda expression.

Comment: Oh my god ... So pretty much the same thing but using .ForEach(...) will do the job ?

Comment: I tried it but again... I'm getting the <styleUrl> 200 times (the values I have in the list)

Comment: The ForEach is just to iterate through all the elements in datesList. Not sure if this is what you're after as in your code I can't see any loops?

Comment: no no.. the placemarks are 20 but then each Point has 10 activities(another important thing from the project), that's why I have 200 rows. There could be different date for every single row (not very often though)